# Can't moderate content from "View Draft" page using Workbench Moderation

Tags: 7, panels

I am using Panels Everywhere, and Workbench Access & Moderation.
I have gotten everything to work, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the block above the content created, that allows the moderator to go from Draft > Needs Review (or another transition).

[image: Screenshot of what I'm trying to find]

9:24 in at http://nodeone.se/node/1024

I can moderate the content from root/node/#/moderation, but can't on the webpage.

Seeing if someone has run into this before and can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  Was so easy it was hard...

Had to configure the "Workbench information" block and set it to "Content" region.  It then would show up above the content.  I also had to add the tags in the "Page elements" panel settings.

Hopefully this will help someone else out.